# How to debug webrtc osx project use xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, webrtc, osx-yosemite, ninja

I have checked out webrtc programe 2019 dec 16. When I run 
`gn gen out/ios --args='target_os="ios" target_cpu="arm64"' --ide=xcode`
It's ready run and debug in ios.

When I run `egn gen out/mac --ide=xcode --rtc_include_tests=true --args='is_debug=true'`,it's ready run in my macbook. However the breakpoint looks useless, and the program can't stop in breakpoint.Should I do some special setting in gn or Xcode? Xcode debuger has atteched this progress.

Answer (score 0):

append "enable_dsyms=true" into --args option